# Eager loading Not retrieving data for child class MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have the following classes defined in my project

```
 public class PolicyDocs
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string PolicyDocID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date Revised")]
    public DateTime DateRevised { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    [DisplayName("Document Name")]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [DisplayName("Version")]
    public string VersionNo { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    [DisplayName("Location")]
    public string DocumentPath { get; set; }

    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PolicyDocumentsCatagory> PolicyDocumentsCatagory { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
  public class PolicyDocumentsCatagory
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    //[Required]
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Active")]
    public Boolean IsActive{ get; set; }

}
```

Data is properly loaded in to the table .
Example:

```
PolicyDocs:
 1 ,"12-Jan-2017", "Document 1","version 1",100

PolicyDocumentsCategory:
 100, "Information Technology", "true".
```

I am using the following query in my Controller Class

```
 _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        //PolicyDocs _Policy = new PolicyDocs();
        var _LPolicies = _context.PolicyDocs.Include(i=> i.PolicyDocumentsCatagory).ToList();
        return PartialView("_GetAllPolicies", _LPolicies);
```

While running the query I am unable to see any data loaded for PolicyDocumentsCategory in "_LPolicies" object. The query is loading data in table "PolicyDocs".

Nor I am able to reference the PolicyDocumentsCategory in VIEW. I can not see the properties of "PolicyDocumentsCatagory" in the view

```
    @model  IEnumerable< MyRTOCloud.DBModels.PolicyDocs>
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <table id="Categories" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Document Name</th>
                <th>Release Date</th>
                <th>Version</th>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var lp in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@lp.PolicyDocumentsCatagory.____</td> // I can not see any peroprty of "PolicyDocumentsCatagory"

                <td>@lp.DocumentName </td>
                <td>@lp.DateRevised </td>
                <td>@lp.VersionNo </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: is the relationship mapped properly? what is the query generated?

Answer (score 0):

`PolicyDocumentsCatagory` is a collection and you have to iterate it in itself or in your case you can combine with a separator as a string.

So, try something like that;

```
<td>@string.Join(",", lp.PolicyDocumentsCatagory.Select(x => x.CategoryID))</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PolicyDocs` class is referencing a single `CategoryID` leading me to assume this is a one-to-many relationship (`PolicyDocs` being the many, `PolicyDocumentsCatagory` being the one). If that is the case, you will want to change your `PolicyDocumentsCatagory` property in `PolicyDocs` to `public virtual PolicyDocumentsCatagory PolicyDocumentsCatagory { get; set; }`. Note the `virtual` part. This is what allows EF to populate the relationship property automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PolicyDocs
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string PolicyDocID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Revised")]
    public DateTime DateRevised { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    [DisplayName("Document Name")]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)]
    [DisplayName("Version")]
    public string VersionNo { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    [DisplayName("Location")]
    public string DocumentPath { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PolicyDocumentsCatagory> PolicyDocumentsCatagory { get; set; }
}

public class PolicyDocumentsCatagory
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string PolicyDocID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey]
    public PolicyDocs PolicyDocs { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Active")]
    public Boolean IsActive{ get; set; }
}
```

Your models are not valid. You need to have a foreign key in your PolicyDocumentsCatagory that referencing to PolicyDocs and there is no need for CategoryID in PolicyDocs.

One **PolicyDocs** has many **PolicyDocumentsCatagory**, while one **PolicyDocumentsCatagory** is referenced to only one **PolicyDocs**. Standard one to many relationship type.